# is the while true in the correct place? also how do i get the user to prompt the user to add something and then to display it in the while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print('Welcome to Loot Box Simulator!')


gems = 0
boxes = 0
boxes_opened = 0
gem_cost = 19.95
gem_amount = 550
box_cost = 100

while True :
    print ('You have',gem_amount, 'gems and', boxes, 'Loot boxes.')
    print ('Choose from the following options:')
    print ('1) Buy gems', gem_amount, 'gems for just', gem_cost)
    print ('2) Buy loot box (costs', box_cost, 'gems)')
    print ('3) Open loot box')
    print('4) View statistics')
    print('5) Quit')
    break
```

My objective is to print these 5 questions and then prompt the user to select one of the 5. if the user selects 1 then 550 gems would be added the print would change. how could i do the above? i am a beginner so if you could please show the changes that could help me understand. thank you

Answer (score 0):

After you have printed out all those instructions you could try to follow up with:

```
while True :
    print ('You have',gem_amount, 'gems and', boxes, 'Loot boxes.')
    print ('Choose from the following options:')
    print ('1) Buy gems', gem_amount, 'gems for just', gem_cost)
    print ('2) Buy loot box (costs', box_cost, 'gems)')
    print ('3) Open loot box')
    print('4) View statistics')
    print('5) Quit')    
    users_choice = input("What do you do? (Press the respective number)") 
    if users_choice == "5":
        break
    else:
        # do whatever you need to do depending on the choice
```

Maybe you also want to look into bundling your activities into functions which you can then call depending on the user's input/interaction.

Comment: Elaborate on what? Did you try adding the lines to your code and checked out what happens?
(I guess you just deleted your "Can you elaborate?" comment...)

Comment: can you elaborate. Lets say after the user selected one i want the whole thing to come back. saying" you have 550gems and 0 loot boxes.choose from the following options: 1....5

Comment: i was editing it. I want the question set to return until the user chooses 5

Comment: I've edited my answer to include checking whether the user has selected '5'.